# errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open',

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed the latest Node.js . and When I tried to install and run the command "npm install concat --save-dev", I received this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEILg.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `concat` the issue you have is because the file `css/icon-font.css` doesn't  exist.

PS: You must add the full path of the folder.
In this case is `Resources/css/css/icon-font.css`

Comment: i tried  to add the css/icon-font.css, but for sorry  the same issue still there .
Do you have any ideas/suggestions as to why this is happening?

Thanks,

A.Naser

Comment: @abdallahnaser I update the answer, but on summary you need to add the full path where the file exists for all the cases the output file and the other ones you want to concatenate.